# Clean up my conditional WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements, where-clause

This code works, I just would like to learn how to clean it up so it's not spanning a ton of lines and the where statement is nice and tidy on just a few lines:

```
SELECT
    case_id, service_type_id 
FROM 
    cases_service_types
WHERE
    dbo.cases_service_types.service_type_id = '3'
    OR dbo.cases_service_types.service_type_id = '4'
    OR dbo.cases_service_types.service_type_id = '5'
    OR dbo.cases_service_types.service_type_id = '6'
    OR dbo.cases_service_types.service_type_id = '8'
    OR dbo.cases_service_types.service_type_id = '9'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`IN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

```
SELECT case_id, 
       service_type_id 
FROM   cases_service_types 
WHERE  dbo.cases_service_types.service_type_id IN ( 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 )
```

Comment: That's awesome and works perfectly! Thanks! One more question, how would i EXCLUDE a group of numbers from the list, and only have it pull in all the others. Like exclude (1, 2, 7, 10, 11). I guess down the road we might be adding more service types, but we know for a fact we will NEVER pull in those five types.

Comment: Oops, nm I figured it out! In that case I would need to use "NOT IN" and specify (1, 2, 7, 10, 11).

Comment: You got it. So, your query would look like `SELECT ... WHERE a IN (...) AND a NOT IN (...)`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    case_id, 
    service_type_id 
FROM 
    dbo.cases_service_types
WHERE
     service_type_id IN ('3', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9' )
```

If you accidentally missed out '7', then even better as:

```
SELECT
    case_id, 
    service_type_id 
FROM 
    dbo.cases_service_types
WHERE
     service_type_id BETWEEN '3' AND '9'
```

Comment: Nope, leaving out the 7 was not a mistake. Sorry, I should have made that more clear in my example. We've got about 30 specific service types and only need about half of them, but they're all cherry picked form the list. Thanks for the reply! BETWEEN sounds really useful as well! Thanks :-)